# When Excel 365 online indicates that a formula in a cell contains an error, where do I see the error message?

Tags: office-365, excel-online

When Excel 365 online indicates that a formula in a cell contains an error, where do I see the error message?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Excel 365 online indicates that a formula in a cell contains an error, there is currently no way to see the detailed error message. One has to infer it oneself based on the formula.